# Php PDO insert query error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run this code to insert a new row in my "questions" table:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions (id,quiz_id,question,image,type,option,answer,explanation,date) 
        VALUES (:id, :quiz_id, :question, :imagesstring, :type, :optionsstring, :answer, :explanation, :date)";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$results = $query->execute(array(
    ":id" => $id,
    ":quiz_id" => $quiz_id,
    ":question" => $question,
    ":imagesstring" => $imagesstring,
    ":type" => $type,
    ":optionsstring" => $optionsstring,
    ":answer" => $answer,
    ":explanation" => $explanation,
    ":date" => $date 
));
```

It says there's a syntax error near, but I cannot find it. I checked the table multiple times and the columns correspond with the variables I inserted. Also the variables have the proper value assigned to them. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

`OPTION` is a reserved keyword. If you don't want to receive any syntax error, you need to escape it using backtick,

```
INSERT INTO questions (id, quiz_id, question, image, type, 
                       `option`, answer, explanation, date)
VALUES(...)
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)